# rrdtool not updating graph correctly

Tags: rrdtool

I've created a rrd database using:

```
rrdtool create /srv/www/htdocs/rrdtool/tanktemp.rrd 
--step 300 /
DS:temp1:GAUGE:600:10:40 /
DS:temp2:GAUGE:600:10:40 /
RRA:MAX:0.5:1:2016
```

I then have a crontab job running every 5 mins that updates the temps.
See pastebin - the values are being updated.
http://pastebin.com/De5tC8GW

I am then running this up create a 24 hour graph:

```
/usr/bin/rrdtool graph /srv/www/htdocs/mrtg/tank_temp.png \
-w 785 -h 120 -a PNG \
--slope-mode \
--start -86400 --end now \
--font DEFAULT:7: \
--title "Tank Temperatures - 24 hours" \
--watermark "`date`" \
--vertical-label "Temperarure(C)" \
--lower-limit 20 \
--right-axis 1:0 \
--x-grid MINUTE:10:HOUR:1:MINUTE:120:0:%R \
--alt-y-grid --rigid \
DEF:temp1=/srv/www/htdocs/rrdtool/tanktemp.rrd:temp1:MAX \
DEF:temp2=/srv/www/htdocs/rrdtool/tanktemp.rrd:temp2:MAX \
LINE1:temp1#ff0000:"Tank 1" LINE1:temp2#0000ff:"Tank 2" \
GPRINT:temp1:LAST:"Tank 1\: %2.1lf C" \
GPRINT:temp2:LAST:"Tank 2\: %2.1lf C"
```

The result is this - clearly something is not right :(

http://postimg.org/image/rcd70zpij/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The temp was below 20 and I had the lower limit set to 20! Doh!!

Changed to:

```
--lower-limit 10 \
```